# Which is Best way to serve multiple wsgi apps using apache2 with different python versions?

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, uwsgi, apache2, wsgi

Right now I've got a python2 django app deployed in my sever using apache2 and mod-wsgi. Now I want to deploy another one, but this is written in python3. My problem is that mod-wsgi is compiled to python2. What are my alternatives to do the deploy? I thouth I could do another deploy using mod-uwsgi for python3.

PD: I'm also using virtualenvs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite an old question but, for those who might still wonder, you can use the uWSGI application server to run applications written in various languages (including Python 2 + Python 3), and then use Apache’s mod_proxy_uwsgi to relay requests to the uWSGI application.